# Unexpected result with Javassist bytecode manipulation and try-with-resources syntax

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, javassist

I’m using Javassist (3.25.0-GA) and Java 8 with a custom Agent to transform bytecode and add print statements to existing `catch{}` clauses. This works for simple cases, but has a problem with the compiled bytecode of the `try-with-resources` syntax.

Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to do and the results when it works correctly on standard `try/catch` blocks:

```java
    // before byte code manipulation
    public void methodWithCatchClause() {
        try {
            throwsAnException();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            handleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

```java
    // after byte code manipulation
    public void methodWithCatchClause() {
        try {
            throwsAnException();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("CATCH CLAUSE!"); // added by Javassist
            handleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

The logic I'm using to transform the bytecode is inspired by another SO post [0]:

```java
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738034/javassist-insert-a-method-at-the-beginning-of-catch-block
    ControlFlow cf = new ControlFlow(ctMethod); // ctMethod == methodWithCatchClause()
    for (ControlFlow.Block block : cf.basicBlocks()) {

        ControlFlow.Catcher catchers[] = block.catchers();
        for (int i = 0; i < catchers.length; i++) {
            ControlFlow.Catcher catcher = catchers[i];

            ControlFlow.Block catcherBlock = catcher.block();

            int position = catcherBlock.position();
            int lineNumber = ctMethod.getMethodInfo().getLineNumber(position);

            ctMethod.insertAt(lineNumber + 1, "System.out.println(\"CATCH CLAUSE!\");");
        }
    }
```

But this code breaks in conjunction with the `try-with-resources` syntax. As a concrete example this code:

```java
    public void tryWithResources() {
        try (TestAutoClosable test = new TestAutoClosable()) {
            test.doStuff();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            handleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Turns into this after code generation:

```java
   public void tryWithResources() {
        try {
            TestAutoClosable test = new TestAutoClosable();
            Throwable var2 = null;

            try {
                System.out.println("CATCH CLAUSE!");
                test.doStuff();
            } catch (Throwable var12) {
                var2 = var12;
                throw var12;
            } finally {
                if (test != null) {
                    if (var2 != null) {
                        try {
                            test.close();
                        } catch (Throwable var11) {
                            var2.addSuppressed(var11);
                        }
                    } else {
                        test.close();
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception var14) {
            System.out.println("CATCH CLAUSE!");
            System.out.println("CATCH CLAUSE!");
            System.out.println("CATCH CLAUSE!");
            // this goes on for 15 more entries...
            this.handleException(var14);
        }

    }
```

This of course is causing "CATCH CLAUSE!" to be printed multiple times in odd places. It might be helpful to mention that empty catch clauses, regardless of `try/catch` syntax, break in a similar fashion (maybe the underlying cause is related?).

I would expect something closer to this as the end result:

```java
    public void tryWithResources() {
        try {
            TestAutoClosable test = new TestAutoClosable();
            Throwable var2 = null;

            try {
                test.noop();
            } catch (Throwable var12) {
                System.out.println("CATCH CLAUSE!");
                var2 = var12;
                throw var12;
            } finally {
                if (test != null) {
                    if (var2 != null) {
                        try {
                            test.close();
                        } catch (Throwable var11) {
                            var2.addSuppressed(var11);
                        }
                    } else {
                        test.close();
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception var14) {
            this.handleException(var14);
        }

    }
```

I'm trying to figure out if I have a simple error in my code or if my approach is entirely wrong. I would appreciate any help with the matter. Thanks in advance.

[0] [Javassist: insert a method at the beginning of catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738034/javassist-insert-a-method-at-the-beginning-of-catch-block)

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354150/8-branches-for-try-with-resources-jacoco-coverage-possible? When compiling try with resources, the generated bytecode contains many hidden exception handlers.

Comment: It looks like the same ControlFlow.Block is used by multiple Catchers. You want to avoid adding your print statement to a block if you've already done that before. Hopefully ASM uses the same instance of the ControlFlow.Block class; if that's the case you can keep a HashSet of Blocks that you've already added your print statement to, and check in that Set before adding your print statement.

Comment: The bytecode catch constructs are not exact matches of the Java language constructs. This does not only affect how `finally` or try-with-resource get compiled, but also `synchronized` blocks. In the case of try-with-resource, the code rarely maps to ordinary language constructs. As discussed in [try with resources introduce unreachable bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25746587/2711488) a lot of odd things will go on, especially with older compilers. And the result will depend on the compiler used for the original code, ecj or javac and which version…

Comment: @Antimony - My hope was that regardless of the bytecode generated from the try-with-resources syntax, I'd be able to hook into any `catch` clauses, regardless of their origin since this agent will run on systems without source code to reference. Ideally it would be very "dumb" and just seek `catch` clauses with Javassist, but maybe I was being a bit too eager with that goal.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - I actually started testing out an idea like that and while it did reduce the repeated entries by checking a `HashSet` against blocks, some of the bytecode transformations were still in the wrong place (like completely outside of the `catch` clause). It feels a bit closer to what I need, but I'm concerned my approach isn't feasible at all in the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Holger - Are you thinking that this is just something that isn't really solvable given the nuances with bytecode, at least with Javassist and my overall approach? Maybe something lower-level is needed with straight bytecode scanning and manipulation?

Comment: The limitations of the bytecode do not change when using a tool at a lower lower level. Still, I prefer doing bytecode manipulations at a lower level only, as it provides a better mental model of what’s going on and what is possible.